# Find sum of possible subarray combinations given min and max values don't exceed k

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures

I recently had to solve a coding challenge for an interview, I was able to get the proper solution, but my code didn't execute in the time constraints for very large datasets. I've been wracking my brain trying to think of how I could have optimized it further and so far haven't been able to think of a solution.

Here's the problem: Given an array list of integers, find the number of possible contiguous segments such that the difference between the maximum and minimum values in the segment doesn't exceed k.

```
Example: array = [1, 2, 7], k = 3
[1] = max(1) - min(1) = 0 < k = good
[1,2] = max(1,2) - min(1,2) = 1 < k = good
[1,2,7] = max(1,2,7) - min(1,2,7) = 6 > k = bad
[2] = max(2) - min(2) = 0 < k = good
[2,7] = max(2,7) - min(2,7) = 5 > k = bad
[7] = max(7) - min(7) = 0 < k = good
there are 4 possible segments that meet the criteria.
```

Here's my solution in Java that gives the right answer, but doesn't calculate fast enough on large datasets. I should mention I'm not allowed to change the method params. How else could this be optimized further?

```
public static int possibleSegments(int k, List<Integer> weights) {
    int possibleSegments = weights.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
        int max = weights.get(i);
        int min = weights.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < weights.size(); j++) {
            int nextSegmentWeight = weights.get(j);
            if (nextSegmentWeight > max) {
                max = nextSegmentWeight;
            } else if (nextSegmentWeight < min) {
                min = nextSegmentWeight;
            }

            if (max - min <= k) {
                possibleSegments++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return possibleSegments;
}
```

Comment: The easiest first step to speed this up is to use `int[]` instead of `List<Integer>`. The short answer is it reduces the total overhead of accessing a value and improves cache locality.

Comment: Try to think a bit more outside the box. There are some optimizations you can apply when looking at the problem at a more meta level. If a subarray from `i` to `j` passes, so will every subarray between `i` and `j`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all maximum and minimum in subarrays for a given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879556/find-all-maximum-and-minimum-in-subarrays-for-a-given-array)

Answer (score 0):

The top voted answer in the link provided by Alexander did indeed improve the execution time, but significantly increased the number of loop iterations. I modified that top answer a little bit and got a solution that has the same number of loop iterations as my original question, but significantly reduced execution time.

```
public static int possibleSegments2(int k, List<Integer> weights) {
    int possibleSegments = weights.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
        int max = weights.get(i);
        int min = weights.get(i);

        int j;
        for (j = i + 1; j < weights.size(); j++) {
            int nextSegmentWeight = weights.get(j);
            max = Math.max(max, nextSegmentWeight);
            min = Math.min(min, nextSegmentWeight);

            if (max - min > k) {
                break;
            }
        }

        possibleSegments += (j - i) - 1;
    }

    return possibleSegments;
}
```

Comment: Time complexity does not changed for this solution? What is benefit of this one respect to other one?

Comment: Instead of incrementing the possible segments for every single possible segment, we only increment the possible segments everytime we've found a maximum possible contiguous segment. The processing difference of not updating the possibleSegments variable so often resulted in local processing times that were almost half of what they were before.

Comment: Are sure? It's possible to present more details?